# Scope value is not getting updated even though the rootscope has the value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-rootscope

I have view

```
<div ng-controller="DisplayController">
    <display-view style="width:{{model.width}}" value={{model.value}}</display-view>
</div>
```

Given my controller as

```
angularModule.controller("DisplayController",function($scope,$rootScope){
    $rootScope.model = DisplayModel;
    this.setInputValue = function(value){
        console.log($rootScope.model);
        $rootScope.model.value =  value;
        console.log($rootScope.model);
        $scope.model.value = $rootScope.model.value;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

Model as

```
var DisplayModel = {
    width:'193px',
    height:'25px',
    value:''
}
```

on some element click I'm calling the setInputValue function:

```
element.bind('click', function(event){
    console.log(event + '..event..');
    DispController.setInputValue(event.target.value);
});
```

display-view is

```
angularModule.directive('displayView',function(){

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller : "DisplayController",
    template: '<input type="text" style={{widthValue}} value={{value}}>',
    link:function(scope,element,attrs){
       scope.widthValue = attrs.style;
       scope.value = attrs.value;
    }
}

})
```

where the value in $rootScope is not getting updated to the view.
How to resolve this issue.

Comment: `display-view` seems to be a directive. Can you share the code corresponding to it ? It'll be better if you could make a  plunkr to demonstrate your issue

Comment: included the display-view code

Comment: Where does `DispController` come from?

Comment: i have specified that in link attribute of other directive. link: function(scope,element,attrs,DispController){
   scope.value = attrs.value;
   scope.className = attrs.class;
   element.bind('click',function(event){

    console.log(event + '..event..');
   DispController.setInputValue(event.target.value);

   });

Comment: Are you sure `value={{model.value}}` shouldn't be `value="{{model.value}}"`?

Answer (score 0):

Here we will have to include replace:true. This will append the value and style to the input element in the display-view directive.

```
angularModule.directive('displayView',function(){
  return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace:true,
  template: '<input type="text">'
}
})
```

Other way to display is by isolating the scope

```
angularModule.directive('displayView',function(){
return {
restrict: 'E',
scope:{
widthValue: "@",
value : "@"
},
template: '<input type="text" style={{widthValue}} value={{value}}>',
link:function(scope,element,attrs){

}
}
})
```